# Status Code 403 Forbidden (Webhooks Zapier to Zipwhip)

Tags: zapier

It says in the SOLUTION.

"Contact your account administrator or ensure that you have the required permissions for the step."

Do I need to contact the support of Zipwhip to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just went through this and literally spent a good 12 hours on this.
This might not answer the question for you, but it may give you some insight on what to do.

I was using a webhook to send data to my own server.  It was giving me a 503 forbidden.  It was successful from Pipedrive and Hookdeck and Postman, but not with Zapier webhooks. I asked Zapier for help and they said it was the server (I have a self-managed VPS) which means it was on me to figure out.

I called Godaddy, but they couldn't figure it out. I looked through my error logs and could see the calls coming in and being rejected.  I knew they were from Zapier, so I whitelisted the ips listed in the error and it worked!

I've never heard of Zipwhip until now and really couldnt find much as to this issue in their documentation, but if it were me, I would reach out to them and see if they can whitelist Zapier's IP address.

For whatever its worth, these are the Zapier ips I have whitelisted:

- 54.86.9.50
- 54.85.112.125
- 45.146.164.110

Comment: Thanks for the feedback man, their support already contacted me and said there is some issues in routing line and need to be fix by their Porting Team. I will give to them the IPS that could help them.

Comment: @JestoniPaderon sorry I didnt see your response. Did this get resolved?